# Disk 100% load with no apparent loaders

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I have a problem on my notebook, that it loads extremely slow. In task manager I can see, that HDD load is 100%, while there is no apparent processes, which are responsible for that load

[image]

[image]

What may be the cause?

Comment: Use Resource Monitor to see which files are being accessed.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Adding to @DavidMarshall comment. You can check you drive's health if there are any bad sectors or drive being highly fragmented. Using [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler) would be one of the options to do this check.

Comment: Dims I don't get notified unless you use @. The performance tab on Task Manager has a link 'open Resource Manager' in English or type resmon in the search box.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an actual screenshot? Also, specs on the device.

Answer (score 1):

The UnistoreDB folder is used by Windows Universal apps. Try disallowing Apps running in the background (Settings>Privacy>Background apps). Start with Groove, Xbox and Photos, which may be syncing in the background.

Avast is also scanning a lot. It's surprising that your Task Manager shows processes for Kaspersky and Defender. Consider removing all antivirus except Defender.

Without knowing the specification of your device, 2GB/s is low to cause a 100% load. Also, some of the low priority response times are very large. The disk may need defragmentation or be too full. In the worst case it may be failing.

Comment: How to be sure it is failing?

Comment: @Dims Most computers have diagnostics that you can access from the BIOS menu when starting. Try esc, F8, F10.  Check the manufacturer's website for user/service manuals. Is it only slow during start-up or all the time?